# Bitcoin client IRC - a potential network weak link?

Tags: client, development, protocol, irc

I'm currently learning more and more about the Bitcoin protocol and I`m wondering if using an IRC channel as the source to find your Bitcoin peers is a potential weak link of the Bitcoin network?

From what I understand the channel is hosted on irc.lfnet.org , so if that website was brought down normal clients would be unable to find peers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They'd have no problem finding peers for several reasons:

1. Once the client finds a single peer, it can get a list of peers from that peer.
2. The client has a built-in list of about 500 peer IP addresses known to be stable.
3. The client knows several DNS names (such as `bitseed.xf2.org` and `dnsseed.bluematt.me`) that resolve to lists of Bitcoin peers.
4. The client stores peer addresses in a local database.

In fact, IRC has been removed from the Bitcoin client since 2013.

Answer (score 9):

New clients that do not yet have addresses stored in the addr.dat will use irc as a bootstrapping mechanism.  Even with this limited role, using IRC exposes a weakness: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Weaknesses#Cancer_nodes

The IRC bootstrapping will be going away in the future [Edit: as David write, it is deprecated in the latest version], in favor of the dnsseed method: 
 - http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=24457.msg305424#msg305424
 - http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Network#IRC